# Deleting files based on day within filename

Tags: python

I have a directory with files like: `data_Mon_15-8-22.csv`, `data_Tue_16-8-22.csv`, `data_Mon_22-8-22.csv` etc and I am trying to delete all but the Monday files. However, my script doesn't seem to differentiate between the filenames and just deletes everything despite me stating it. Where did I go wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

My Code:

```
def file_delete():
    directory = pathlib.Path('/Path/To/Data')
    for file in directory.glob('data_*.csv'):
        if file != 'data_Mon_*.csv':
            os.remove(file)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all Monday files start with "data_Mon_" then you might use str.startswith:

```
def file_delete():
    directory = pathlib.Path('/Path/To/Data')
    for file in directory.glob('data_*.csv'):
        if not file.name.startswith('data_Mon_'):
            os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if file != 'data_Mon_*.csv'
```

There's two problems here:

`file` is compared against the string `'data_Mon_*.csv'`. Since `file` isn't a string, these two objects will never be equal. So the `if` condition will always be true. To fix this, you need to get the file's name, rather than using the file object directly.

Even if you fix this, the string `'data_Mon_*.csv'` is literal. In other words, the `*` is a `*`. Unlike `directory.glob('data_*.csv')`, this will only match a `*` rather than match "anything" as in a glob expression. In order to fix this, you need to use a regular expression to match against your file name.